# How to write a condition when a date field should be sorted according to date filters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a date filters named start_date and end_date and I have to sort the Contacts based on this filters and sort according to created_at (a date field).

This is my method where I am listing all the records:

```
  def execute_records
    @items = []
    if @params[:category_id] && !@params[:category_id].empty?
      contacts = Contact.joins(:company).where(active: true, account_id: @user.id, companies: {category_id: @params[:category_id], active: true})
    else
      contacts = Contact.joins(:company).where(active: true, account_id: @user.id, companies: {active: true})
    end
    contacts.includes(company: [:addresses, :category, :lead_source]).each do |contact|
      @items << Report.new(contact) if contact.is_a?(Contact)
    end
  end
```

Here in the above method I just wanted to add a condition where **created_at is in between start_date and end_date**. created_at is field in contacts table.

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
Contact.joins(:company).where(active: true, account_id: @user.id, companies: {created_at: Time.new(params[:start_date] || 0)..Time.new(params[:end_date] || Time.new(3000))})
```